# Flask - Sending zipfile contains absolute path

Tags: python, flask, server, download

My flask app has a function that compresses log files in a directory into a zip file and then sends the file to the user to download. The compression works, except that when the client receives the zipfile, the zip contains a series of folders that matches the absolute path of the original files that were zipped in the server. However, the zipfile that was made in the server static folder does not.

Zipfile contents in static folder: "log1.bin, log2.bin"

Zipfile contents that was sent to user: "/home/user/server/data/log1.bin, /home/user/server/data/log2.bin"

I don't understand why using "send_file" seems to make this change to the zip file contents and fills the received zip file with sub folders. The actual contents of the received zip file do in fact match the contents of the sent zip file in terms of data, but the user has to click through several directories to get to the files. What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route("/download")
def download():
    os.chdir(data_dir)
    if(os.path.isfile("logs.zip")):
        os.remove("logs.zip")
    log_dir = os.listdir('.')
    log_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('logs.zip', 'w')
    for log in log_dir:
        log_zip.write(log)
    log_zip.close()
    return send_file("logs.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: checkout the doc, they have some options for send file direct from server / static folder https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: Thanks for sending me here. I came across the send_from_directory call and that fixed everything!

Answer (score 1):

Using `send_from_directory(directory, "logs.zip", as_attachment=True)` fixed everything. It appears this call is better for serving up static files.